# Nginx failing to redirect to docker container

Tags: networking, server, apache2, php, nginx

I have the setup

docker-compose:

```
nginx:
    restart: always
    build: nginx/.       // loads nginx:alpine image + copies the config
    ports:
        - 80:80
        - 1337:1337
    links:
        - rose:rose

rose:
    build: rose/.        // simple website, based on node:latest
    restart: always
    expose:
        - 1337
```

nginx.conf:

```
upstream docker-rose {
    server rose:1337;
}

server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:1337;

    gzip on;                                  // + some other gzip crap

    location ~ ^/(.*)/ {

        proxy_pass http://docker-rose;
        proxy_redirect     off;

        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;      // + some other proxy headers thingy
    }
}
```

docker-compose ps:

```
nginx_1          nginx -g daemon off;             Up       0.0.0.0:1337->1337/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp 
rose_1           npm start                        Up       1337/tcp
```

So i expect nginx to listen to outside 1337 port and pass everything to rose via 1337 internal port.

However, when i open localhost:1337 in the browser, i get

> nginx_1         | 2018/04/29 14:57:22 [error] 9#9: *28
>   "/etc/nginx/html/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or
>   directory), client: 172.19.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1",
>   host: "localhost:1337"

It has one job: to redirect everything_from_outside:1337 to internal_container:1337. Why on Earth it tries to load /etc/nginx/html/index.html?

EDIT: So, i got the container id via `docker ps` and logged in via `docker exec -ti %id% sh`. Trying to ping rose:

```
/ # ping rose 
PING rose (172.19.0.11): 56 data bytes 
64 bytes from 172.19.0.11: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.083 ms 
64 bytes from 172.19.0.11: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.116 ms
```

Trying to ping localhost with 1337 port:

```
/ # ping localhost:1337
PING localhost:1337 (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.080 ms
```

Comment: You *do* know that Docker containers run as individual 'systems' within themselves right?  Unless 'rose' resolves inside the Docker container to something *other* than localhost, this won't work.  To make this work *properly* you need to run nginx *outside* of Docker and run it on the host system, because NGINX won't know where to route its own 1337 to (it doesn't know to route it to the other machine's 1337)

Comment: @ThomasWard Isn't that linking thing is going to resolve the internal ip of the container?

Comment: if and only if Docker serves a DNS intermediary to 'point' the names to the IPs properly.  To test this, you'd have to console into the specific Docker instance, and run something like a `nslookup` or a ping to `rose` to see what the name resolves to.  Of course, Docker doesn't run a full system so most of those tools 'don't exist'; we'd need to see the logs from the Docker NGINX instance to really determine what it's doing.

Comment: Also beware the [NGINX Configuration Pitfall of using hostnames to resolve IPs](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#using-a-hostname-to-resolve-addresses), because this can lead to issues sometimes.

Comment: @ThomasWard Hm.. i've added the result of ping, but i'm not really sure if that's correct.

Comment: Also, thanks for warning about using hostnames - but i'm at the dev stage now, so i dont really have the ip that i'd like to use in config. It seems the worst thing that might happen - nginx would not start, but it starts fine for me for now - so hopefully i'm out of that problem, at least this time.

Comment: that was run from the host, not from inside the docker container of nginx, right?

Comment: I mean, i have something similar working at port 80 - it successfully redirects to a couple of services, depending on the request: `location ~ ^/(catalog)/ { proxy_pass http://docker-catalog;`, where docker-catalog is container that listens to 9000 port, and it works fine. Didnt add that to the question for simplicity sake.

Comment: @ThomasWard i believe that was run from container, as i have logged in to the container: https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/edge/engine/reference/commandline/container_exec/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76753/discussion-between-thomas-ward-and-vitalii-vasylenko).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks [Thomas](https://askubuntu.com/users/10616/thomas-ward) for pushing towards irc channel, guys there gave me a correct hint. The problem was with

```
location ~ ^/(.*)/ {
```

It was enough to simplify it to

```
location ~ / {
```

Now it works!